# Forms firing ngSubmit twice on Angular 2.0.1

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

For any form in Angular 2.0.1, whenever I press return or click on the submit button, the `ngSubmit` output is fired twice. I'm already including the `FormsModule` in the application module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  providers: [
    // ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've tried to follow some answers (such as [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9954#issuecomment-231743596) one), but `disableDeprecatedForms` and `provideForms` have been removed since RC6. I've also tried to import the `DeprecatedFormsModule`, but it seems to have been removed as well.

What should I do to prevent the `ngSubmit` to be fired twice?

## UPDATE:

I didn't think the template would matter in this case since it's a known issue and it happens for any form in the application, but here follow one of the forms as an example (stripped out of unnecessary classes and tags):

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login(user)">
  <input [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username" type="email" id="username" required>
  <label for="username">Email</label>

  <input [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="password" type="password" id="password" required>
  <label for="password">Password</label>

  <button>
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Show form code in HTML including button.

Comment: may be you are submitting your form twice firstly at the form tag and secondly on the button named submit check it once or either post you code

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I just included the template for one of the forms.

Comment: your form seems right error is somewhere else, could you please recreate your problem on some plunker ?

Comment: Thanks, now that I've wrote the Plunker I realized it was something else. What's actually firing twice is not the `ngSubmit` as I had previously thought, but the HTTP request (I'm feeling silly I hadn't test that before).

Answer (score 0):

After some some comments I tried to reproduce the error in a Plunker only to realize that the problem was something else entirely. What was being fired twice was not the `ngSubmit`, but the HTTP request.

I was subscribing twice to the same `http.post(args)`, what happens is that I need to call `.share()` so it won't be executed for every subscribe (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37241863/2908285).