# Double api call issue in Angular

Tags: angular, http

I am doing an api call using get method, and i need to pass Authorization in header, when i send Authorization token, it call api two times,

here is my code,

```
GetCount() {
    this.token = 'AbrdhyitT09iubhgsrdhyitT09iubhgsitT09iubhgsrdhyitT09iubhgs459S';
    return this.http.get('MY-API', {
          headers: new Headers({'Authorization': this.token})
        })
}
```

here is my component

```
import {Component,ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpService} from './services/http.service'
import {isDevMode} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _httpService: HttpService) {

    } 
    GetData() {
        this._httpService.GetCount().subscribe((response:any) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
}
```

when i remove Authorization from header, it do only one call

Comment: It is the normal cycle of an Ajax request

Comment: Is the first HTTP request an `OPTIONS` pre-fetch?

Comment: its a OPTION request

Comment: don't you think this is a double load on server ?

Comment: can you post your full component.ts code

Comment: updated, when i remove Authorization, it did only one call

Comment: You are making an cross origin request to a web server, and the browser is performing an OPTIONS request to ask the server if it's allowed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: then why it did not check when i remove Authorization

Comment: A standard `GET` request does not need a pre-fetch `OPTIONS` request to verify, but when you changed the headers the browser can no long assume the web server will allow it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: why -1 ??.........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http.get being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659860/http-get-being-called-twice)