# http GET method calling twice

Tags: angular, rxjs

This question is asked here but still, I could not able to find my answer in those and I believe I have done all my research,

> a. Things what I have done so far:

1. I have tried .share [Link for the Same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241294/angular2-http-post-gets-executed-twice)
2. I have tried to check whether it's a preflight request and found this in my network tab:

[image]

> there is 2 OPTION call and 2 GET call is going . So, we can be sure
>   that its not PREFLIGHT request.

Now comming towards my coding part:

```
Component
------------


    constructor(
            private _notificationService: NotificationService) {
            this.getNotification();
        }


    getNotification() {
            this._notificationService.getNotifications().subscribe(notifications => {
                this.notificationList = notifications;
            });
        }



Service:
-------------

    constructor(private http: Http,private config: Configuration) { }

     getNotifications() {
            const headers = new Headers({
                'c-t-tenant': 'TENANT NAME',
                'c-t-apitoken': 'TOKEN-NAME',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            });
            return this.http.get(this.config.notificationApiUrl, { headers: headers })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
        }
```

I am very much sure that this api is not getting called from somewhere else.
If somebody stucked in this kind of situation please help me here.

> My backend is in Spring Boot and i have implemented CORS filter also:

```
package com.bosch.cb.dashboard.auth;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public SimpleCORSFilter() {
        System.out.println("SimpleCORSFilter init");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");             
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Pragma, Origin,Accept, b-h-apitoken ,X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the component isn't being rendered twice? In other words being called twice and the constructor is therefore being called twice?

Comment: @WesleyCoetzee i am sure.  i checked it by putting console.log inside the constructor of my component and it's getting printed only once.Can you suggest any way in which i can be sure that component is rendered only once?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
constructor( private _notificationService: NotificationService) {
    this.getNotification().subscribe(notifications => {
        this.notificationList = notifications;
    });
 }


getNotification() {
   return this._notificationService.getNotifications();
}
```

or the workaround of

```
constructor( private _notificationService: NotificationService) {
    this.getNotification()
     .first()
     .subscribe(notifications => {
         this.notificationList = notifications;
     });
 }


getNotification() {
   return this._notificationService.getNotifications();
}
```