# RxJS add catch() to an Observable that's been shared

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have the following code I'm using in my Angular (4.0) application during $http calls.

```
return this.httpComponent.post(serviceUrl, request, args)
            .map((res: any) => res.json() as R)
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error'));
```

After testing this I realized multiple subscriptions were triggering the request multiple times. Thanks to this post: [Angular2 http.post gets executed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241294/angular2-http-post-gets-executed-twice) I found out I needed to **share()** the result.

This works to get rid of the multiple calls but now it seems my **catch()** method isn't being hit. I want my **catch()** to **throw** the error.

I tried the two options below but they did not work:

```
return this.httpComponent.post(serviceUrl, request, args)
    .map((res: any) => res.json() as R)
    .share()
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error'));

return this.httpComponent.post(serviceUrl, request, args)
    .map((res: any) => res.json() as R)
    .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || error.json().errorMessage || 'Server error') 
    .share()); //This doesn't make sense since my catch() isn't returning an Observable
```

Anyone know how I can **share()** and **catch(throw...)** at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option you've included in your question attaches the `catch` to the `Observable.throw`. If that is corrected, you should see the behaviour you are expecting:

```js
const source = Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .map((value) => {
    if (value === 2) {
      throw new Error("Boom!");
    }
    console.log(`value: ${value}`)
    return value;
  })
  .catch((error) => Rx.Observable.throw(new Error(`Re-thrown ${error.message}`)))
  .share();

source.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log(`subscription 1: ${value}`),
  (error) => console.log(`subscription 1: ${error}`)
);
source.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log(`subscription 2: ${value}`),
  (error) => console.log(`subscription 2: ${error}`)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The code in my example is actually a typo. I wasn't trying to attach the **share()** to the **throw()**. But your code snippet helped me figure out the problem so I'm accepting your answer. As for my problem, it turns out one of the earliest subscribers didn't have an error handler. So, and this seems like a design flaw imo, all subsequent subscribers would never get the error.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment to @cartant 's answer, if any subscriber doesn't have an error handler (ie: doesn't care about any error scenarios) an exception is thrown and all subsequent subscribers are never informed of the original error.

This seems like a design flaw in my opinion. Here is the example (Copied from @cartant 's answer)

```js
const source = Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .map((value) => {
    if (value === 2) {
      throw new Error("Boom!");
    }
    console.log(`value: ${value}`)
    return value;
  })
  .catch((error) => Rx.Observable.throw(new Error(`Re-thrown ${error.message}`)))
  .share();

source.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log(`subscription 1: ${value}`)
);
source.subscribe(
  (value) => console.log(`subscription 2: ${value}`),
  (error) => console.log(`subscription 2: ${error}`)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI, it seems there is an open issue for this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2180 - so you're not the only person to consider it a flaw.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I definitely think this behavior should be changed.